# Unable to preload links: feature not supported | Symfony & Webpack-Encore

Tags: symfony, webpack, preload, symfony6, webpack-encore

I activated in config/packages/webpack_encore.yaml the preload of script & link tags via HTTP/2 Link header

`preload: true`

But I see this log error from Symfony web server log file at each new request

`unable to preload links: feature not supported`

Any idea on why I got this error and what should I do to activate this feature ?

My base.html.twig used simple Encore entry tags

```
{% block stylesheets %}
   {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
   {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}
```

My webpack_encore.yaml file

```
webpack_encore:
    output_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build'

    script_attributes:
        defer: true
        'data-turbo-track': reload

    link_attributes:
         'data-turbo-track': reload

    preload: true

framework:
    assets:
        json_manifest_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build/manifest.json'
```

Symfony 6.3.1

symfony/webpack-encore-bundle 2.0.1